# A "model plane" or a "plane model": What's the difference?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Which question is correct? If they are both correct, what's the difference between these questions?

> 1. How do you make a **model plane**?
> 2. How do you make a **plane model**?

Comment: "Model plane" is more commonly used. As a mathematician, the word "plane model" reminds me of a model of some system drawn on a plane, like a plane diagram or a plane graph.

Comment: In the US "model airplane" is a hair more idiomatic.  The term "model (air)plane", though, is ambiguous in terms of whether it refers to a flying model or simply a static representation of the aircraft structure.  "(Air)plane model" would be usually taken to mean the static representation.